# Include another project using Gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have the following directory structure:

```
dir
 |
 |---project1
 |     |
 |     |--build.gradle
 |     |--src/main/java/com/bpd/app
 |                               |
 |                               |--SomeClass.java
 |
 |---project2
       |
       |--build.gradle
       |--src/main/java/com/bpd/app
                                 |
                                 |--AnotherClass.java
                                 |--MyClass.java
```

Both are separate Java projects, but `SomeClass` will not compile because it cannot find `MyClass`.

I can add `project2` to the build path for `project1` using Eclipse (and `SomeClass` will then compile), but I want to know how to do it using Gradle. Is it possible? How can I make Gradle add `project2` to the build path for `project1`?

Here's the `build.gradle` file for one of the projects. Only the library dependencies differ.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'war'

apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'pmd'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile "javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1"

  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.13'
  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.13'
  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.13'
  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.13'

  compile 'javax.ejb:ejb-api:3.0'

  compile 'org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.0.0'
  compile 'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:2.6.2'
  compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.11.2'

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.2.0'
}

sourceSets.test.resources {
  srcDirs = ["src/test/java", "src/test/resources"]
  exclude "**/package-info.java"
}

jar {
  from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}

tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}

checkstyle {
  toolVersion = "6.13"
}
```